# Loading a Nunjucks template with Electron.js

Tags: javascript, html, electron, templating, nunjucks

I would like to use a nunjucks render as my HTML for a window in my electron app but I can't find a way, is it possible? From what I have seen there are 2 ways to load HTML in window:

```
  // Load a remote URL
  win.loadURL('https://github.com')

  // Or load a local HTML file
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/index.html`)
```

And when I render my nunjucks template I have a string stored in a javascript variable:

```
render = nunjucks.render('./template/Template.html', data);
```

How can I use that string as an html for my window?

Many thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can pack your HTML into a data URI and pass that to win.loadURL:

```js
const html = "<html><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1></body></html>";
win.loadURL("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(html));
```

With your nunjucks render:

```js
const render = nunjucks.render('./template/Template.html', data);
win.loadURL("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(render));
```